# Standardise textual input data

Tags: c#, normalization, levenshtein-distance, standardized

We receive a lot of typed data from uncontrolled external sources. The data covers makes/models of home appliances. Because we have no control to force validation/auto-complete the spellings/formatting of this data is incredibly messy.

I know things like elastic search enable ignoring of spelling mistakes when querying. However I'd like to be able to group and automatically normalise the data so it can be grouped.

I've thought of calculating the levenshtein distance between any given text and grouping similar entries together. However because many of these appliances have model numbers, capacities etc in their names it will cause a problematic number of false matches. Not to mention be a fairly computationally intense operation.

Example using residential gas boilers

- VAILLANT  Ecotec Pro 28
- VAILLIANT  Ecotec Pro 28
- Vailliant Eco Tec 28 Pro
- VAILLIANT  turbomax 242/2-5
- POTTERTON  Promax Combi 28 HE Plus
- POTTERTON  promax 28

The first 3 and final 2 being the same.
Obviously there's a lot of scope for mistakes including formatting and spelling.

Comment: Ha! Sounds like a nasty problem. The only other approach I know is [N-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)s, but I never used it myself. Just a thought.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725930/duplicate-elimination-of-similar-company-names/44754721#44754721