# Duplicate elimination of similar company names

Tags: duplicates, nlp, linguistics

I have a table with company names. There are many duplicates because of human input errors. There are different perceptions if the subdivision should be included, typos, etc. I want all these duplicates to be marked as one company "1c":

```
+------------------+
|     company      |
+------------------+
| 1c               |
| 1c company       |
| 1c game studios  |
| 1c wireless      |
| 1c-avalon        |
| 1c-softclub      |
| 1c: maddox games |
| 1c:inoco         |
| 1cc games        |
+------------------+
```

I identified [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as a good way to eliminate typos. However, when the subdivision is added the Levenshtein distance increases dramatically and is no longer a good algorithm for this. Is this correct?

In general I have barely any experience in Computational Linguistics so I am at a loss what methods I should choose.

**What algorithms would you recommend for this problem?** I want to implement it in java. Pure SQL would also be okay. Links to sources would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429385/how-do-i-normalize-a-large-user-generated-data-set-of-company-names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974972/how-to-normalize-company-names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835318/normalize-data-according-to-business-entity-legal-name-class-of-business-dns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a difficult problem. A magic search keyword that might help you is "**normalization**" - while sometimes it means very different things ("database normalization" is unrelated, for example), you are effectively trying to normalize your input here.

A simple solution is to use Levenshtein distance with token awareness. The Python library Fuzzy Wuzzy does this and [this blog post](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) introduces how it works with motivating examples. The basic idea is simple enough you should be able to implement it in Java without much difficulty.

At a high level, the idea is to split the input into tokens on whitespace and maybe punctuation, then sort the tokens and treat them as a set, then use the set intersection size - allowing for fuzzy matching - as a metric.

Some related links:

- [Are there any good libraries available for doing normalization of company names? - Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/115/are-there-any-good-libraries-available-for-doing-normalization-of-company-names)
- [NEMO: Extraction and normalization of organization names from PubMed affiliation strings](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2990275/?report=classic)
- [Automatic gazetteer enrichment with user-geocoded data](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gelern/pdfs/GeoCrowd_Upload.pdf) - For place names, this basically creates a list of "true" names and then uses fuzzy lookup.
- [Normalizing company names with SPARQL and DBpedia - bobdc.blog](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2012/12/normalizing-company-names-with.html) - Uses Wikipedia redirect information.